# R reshape and subset data frames in list

Tags: r, dataframe

My problem is as follows: I would like to subset certain combination columns of each data frame in new data frames. I need to do it like that, because I want to every DF seperatly for further calculations.

1.I organized my data in a list of four data frames each of them contains one variables for one years.

```
  nms     <- c(paste0("tiva.EXGR.wide",c(1995,       
  2005)),paste0("tiva.VA.wide",c(1995, 2005)))
  df.list <- lapply(nms, get)
```

Data frame 1: Exports measure 1, year 1995, 26 columns:

```
 |COU |PAR | Time| C01T05| C10T14| C15T16|
 |:---|:---|----:|------:|------:|------:|
 |ARG |ARG | 1995|   0.00|   0.00|   0.00|
 |ARG |AUS | 1995|   0.83|   0.17|  14.87|
 |ARG |AUT | 1995|   1.66|   0.00|   2.59|
```

Data frame 2: Exports measure 2, year 1995, 26 columns:

```
 |COU |PAR | Time| C01T05| C10T14| C15T16|
 |:---|:---|----:|------:|------:|------:|
 |ARG |ARG | 2005|   0.00|   0.00|   0.00|
 |ARG |AUS | 2005|   2.50|   2.20|  22.48|
 |ARG |AUT | 2005|   3.57|   0.09|  13.64|
```

If I would repeate it for all dataframes I could do it like this.

tive.VA.2005.10t14<-tiva.VA.2005.wide[, c(1, 2, 5)]

So that the result would look like this:

```
 |COU |    ARG|  AUS|  AUT|
 |:---|------:|----:|----:|
 |ARG |   0.00| 2.20| 0.09|
 |AUS | 492.73| 0.00| 8.36|
 |AUT |   0.05| 0.50| 0.00|
 |BEL |   0.26| 0.29| 1.30|
 |BGR |   0.01| 0.02| 1.19|
 |BRA | 823.07| 8.18| 0.92|
```

But I would like to programm it in such a way that I would run a loop and create a data frame in a new list. In each of the dataframes I want to include three columns, the first and two from the columns original dataframe and then a third columns from that data frames, which moves on in each iteration. I tried to do it in this way.

```
for (i in 4:26) {
  EXGR.1995<-NULL
  EXGR.2005<-NULL
  EXGR.1995[[i]]<-(df.list[[1]][,c(1,2,i)])
  EXGR.2005[[i]]<-(df.list[[3]][,c(1,2,i)])
  }
```

Comment: If you have exactly the same column in all the data sets, why are you insisting on keeping them in a list?

Comment: In the end my goal is to have a data frame for each industry, where the columns are the values for each export from COU to PAR. I need this kind of data structure to save it and use it for calculating the centrality of each industry. The way I programmed this in stata it is that it takes one file for each industry at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data in a list called `myList`, you can easily convert the whole thing to a data frame:

```
myDF <- do.call(rbind, myList)
```

Then you can try reshaping what you want.